# Optimising MySQL queries across hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures, query-optimization

I have a fairly stable directed graph of order ~100k vertices and size ~1k edges.  It is two-dimensional insofar as its vertices can be identified by a pair of integers `(x, y)` (of cardinality ~100 x ~1000) and all edges are strictly increasing in `x`.

There is furthermore a dictionary of ~1k `(key, val)` pairs associated with each vertex.

I am currently storing the graph in a MySQL database across three (InnoDB) tables: a table of vertices (which I don't think is relevant to my question, so I have omitted to include both it and the foreign key constraints that refer to it in my extracts below); a table which holds the dictionaries; and a 'closure table' of connected vertices as described so eloquently by Bill Karwin.

The table of vertex dictionaries is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `VertexDictionary` (
  `x`   smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `y`   smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `val` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`x`, `y`  , `key`),
  KEY  `dict` (`x`, `key`, `val`)
);
```

and the closure table of connected vertices as:

```
CREATE TABLE `ConnectedVertices` (
  `tail_x` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tail_y` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `head_x` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `head_y` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY   (`tail_x`, `tail_y`, `head_x`),
  KEY `reverse` (`head_x`, `head_y`, `tail_x`),
  KEY `fx` (`tail_x`, `head_x`),
  KEY `rx` (`head_x`, `tail_x`)
);
```

There is also a dictionary of `(x, key)` pairs such that for each such pair, all vertices identified with that `x` have within their dictionaries a value for that `key`.  This dictionary is stored in a fourth table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SpecialKeys` (
  `x`   smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`x`),
  KEY `xkey`  (`x`, `key`)
);
```

I often wish to extract the set of keys used in the dictionaries of all vertices having a particular `x=X`, together with the associated value of any `SpecialKeys` connected to the left:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `v`.`key`,
  `u`.`val`
FROM
       `ConnectedVertices` AS `c`
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `u` ON (`u`.`x`, `u`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`tail_x`, `c`.`tail_y`)
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `v` ON (`v`.`x`, `v`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`head_x`, `c`.`head_y`)
  JOIN `SpecialKeys`       AS `k` ON (`k`.`x`, `k`.`key`) = (`u`.`x`, `u`.`key`)
WHERE
  `v`.`x` = X
;
```

for which the `EXPLAIN` output is:

```
id   select_type   table   type     possible_keys           key       key_len   ref                                rows   Extra
 1   SIMPLE        k       index    PRIMARY,xkey            xkey          154   NULL                                 40   Using index; Using temporary
 1   SIMPLE        c       ref      PRIMARY,reverse,fx,rx   PRIMARY         2   db.k.x                                1   Using where
 1   SIMPLE        v       ref      PRIMARY,dict            PRIMARY         4   const,db.c.head_y                   136   Using index
 1   SIMPLE        u       eq_ref   PRIMARY,dict            PRIMARY       156   db.c.tail_x,db.c.tail_y,db.k.key      1   Using where
```

But this query takes ~10s to complete.  Been banging my head against a brick wall trying to improve matters, but to no avail.

Can the query be improved, or should I consider a different data structure?  Extremely grateful for your thoughts!

---

**UPDATE**

I'm still getting nowhere with this, although I did rebuild the tables and found the `EXPLAIN` output to be slightly different (as now shown above, the number of rows fetched from `v` had increased from 1 to 136!); the query is still taking ~10s to execute.

I really don't understand what's going on here.  Queries to obtain all `(x, y, SpecialValue)` and all `(x, y, key)` tuples are both very fast (~30ms and ~150ms respectively), yet essentially joining the two takes over fifty times longer than their combined time... how can I improve the time taken to perform that join?

Output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%';` below:

```
Variable_name                    Value
------------------------------------------------------------
have_innodb                      YES
ignore_builtin_innodb            ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing         ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index       ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  2097152
innodb_autoextend_increment      8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode         1
innodb_buffer_pool_size          1179648000
innodb_change_buffering          inserts
innodb_checksums                 ON
innodb_commit_concurrency        0
innodb_concurrency_tickets       500
innodb_data_file_path            ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir             /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_doublewrite               ON
innodb_fast_shutdown             1
innodb_file_format               Antelope
innodb_file_format_check         Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table            ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit   1
innodb_flush_method              O_DIRECT
innodb_force_recovery            0
innodb_io_capacity               200
innodb_lock_wait_timeout         50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog   OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size           8388608
innodb_log_file_size             134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group        2
innodb_log_group_home_dir        /rdsdbdata/log/innodb
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct       75
innodb_max_purge_lag             0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups       1
innodb_old_blocks_pct            37
innodb_old_blocks_time           0
innodb_open_files                300
innodb_read_ahead_threshold      56
innodb_read_io_threads           4
innodb_replication_delay         0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout       OFF
innodb_spin_wait_delay           6
innodb_stats_method              nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata         ON
innodb_stats_sample_pages        8
innodb_strict_mode               OFF
innodb_support_xa                ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops           30
innodb_table_locks               ON
innodb_thread_concurrency        0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay        10000
innodb_use_sys_malloc            ON
innodb_version                   1.0.16
innodb_write_io_threads          4
```

Comment: Do you need a full join? What about a left join?

Comment: @David: On which table(s)?  I can't see how I would use a `LEFT JOIN` here...

Comment: What's the size of your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? Post the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%'`, it might be just a case of poorly tuned innodb engine.

Comment: @N.B.: It's a standard Amazon RDS instance... `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is ~1GB - full configuration of InnoDB options shown above.

Comment: If you run `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT.. (your query here); SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1` - that might tell us where MySQL spends the most time on.

Comment: @N.B.: Thanks for the suggestion.  Almost the entire time is spent "Copying to tmp table".  If one removes the `DISTINCT`, then ~1.1m rows are returned; with it, the result set is reduced to 624 rows.  I presume that MySQL is attempting to copy all 1.1m into the tmp table, filtering out duplicate rows in the process?  In which case, I presume that the query would be significantly improved if duplicate rows could be somehow removed (on indexes?) prior to copying into the tmp table?  Is that even possible...?

Comment: Now here's a catch - that isn't actually "copying to tmp table" that's taking up time, it's the step before that. From quickly looking at your tables, one thing I notice is that you have way too many indexes, you could probably get away with a single composite index in each table. But since I just skimmed it (at work, can't really dedicate at the moment), I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @N.B.: You may well be right for the single use-case given above, but of course there are many other types of queries I run against this data which require some of those indexes... could their presence really slow down this query?

Comment: @Daryl: Are they not all shown in the `CREATE TABLE` statements quoted above?

Comment: You say "There is also a dictionary of (x, key) pairs". But the 'SpecialKeys' table has a primary key on 'x' only. So there is no pair, but only a dictionary of x values. Each 'x' value having one 'key' value. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Skrol29: You are correct in reading that each `x` is associated with at most one (special) `key` - I *think* such a map from a key (`x`) to a value (`key`) is what is meant by a "dictionary"(?); by "pairs", I was referring to such tuples.

Comment: I also wonder why you query use a join on (k.key=u.key). Is there a true reason of wanting tail vertices only with the key equal to SpecialKeys? And why the final SELECT return the key of the head, and the value of the tail?

Comment: @Skrol29: The query's logic is correct for my purposes - it returns precisely the right data, just takes too long to do it.

Comment: @eggyal: ok thanks. But not having any clue about the logic won't help to find another way of querying.

Comment: @Skrol29: I'm not sure I understand?  The question details the logic that the query is implementing: "I often wish to extract the set of keys used in the dictionaries of all vertices having a particular `x=X`, together with the associated value of any `SpecialKeys` connected to the left".

Comment: @eggyal: I was thinking that knowing the model a little better could help to find another way of querying your data. And you also said "should I consider a different data structure". This can be reply only if we know more. For example: I cannot see if (x,y) is a good identifier for Vertices considering you want to run SQL queries over them. But anyway, let's not go this way.

Comment: @eggyal Have you tried avoiding the varchar key join as I had suggested in my last 'answering' iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Without spending time testing it, you provided an incomplete example? 
you should definitely try **reordering** of joined tables. Explain output provides some info, let's say ordering by key_len should be heuristically fastest. First table to be filtered on should be listed as last in case the optimizer is not able to figure that out, I believe.

So, let's say 'c, v, k, u' order is the best.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `v`.`key`,
  `u`.`val`
FROM
  `VertexDictionary`  AS `u`
  JOIN `SpecialKeys`       AS `k` ON (`k`.`x`, `k`.`key`) = (`u`.`x`, `u`.`key`)
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `v`
  JOIN `ConnectedVertices` AS `c` ON (`u`.`x`, `u`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`tail_x`, `c`.`tail_y`)
           AND (`v`.`x`, `v`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`head_x`, `c`.`head_y`)
WHERE
  `v`.`x` = X
;
```

'rows' would suggest 'c/u, k, v' order, but that depends on data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `v`.`key`,
  `u`.`val`
FROM
  `VertexDictionary`  AS `u`
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `v`
  JOIN `SpecialKeys`       AS `k` ON (`k`.`x`, `k`.`key`) = (`u`.`x`, `u`.`key`)
  JOIN `ConnectedVertices` AS `c` ON (`u`.`x`, `u`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`tail_x`, `c`.`tail_y`)
                                 AND (`v`.`x`, `v`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`head_x`, `c`.`head_y`)
 WHERE
  `v`.`x` = X
;
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** (avoiding the varchar join):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `v`.`key`,
  `u`.`val`
FROM
       `ConnectedVertices` AS `c`
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `u` ON (`u`.`x`, `u`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`tail_x`, `c`.`tail_y`)
  JOIN `VertexDictionary`  AS `v` ON (`v`.`x`, `v`.`y`  ) = (`c`.`head_x`, `c`.`head_y`)
WHERE
  (`u`.`x`, `u`.`key`) IN (SELECT `k`.`x`, `k`.`key` FROM `SpecialKeys` AS `k`)
AND
  `v`.`x` = X
;
```

Comment: Were you intending that I use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`?  If not, the optimiser reduces your proposed queries to the same as my original (the `EXPLAIN` output and time-to-execute are no different); with `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, the first query had not completed after an hour (so I gave up) and the second is still running after 10 minutes...

Comment: I have no idea what a straight_join is. If optimizer changes those queries to the same you used, you should try some query hints to reorder those tables, I do not know mysql specifics on this.

Comment: Looking at it again, the problem might be with the temporary table being created on disk rather in memory, if the query cannot be changed to avoid it, try increasing tmp_table_size variable (maybe you'll need to increase max_heap_table_size too, as it is used if tmp_tabl_size is bigger)

Comment: Thanks @MarianP.  AFAIK, the MySQL optimiser will reorder joins unless one uses the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` keyword to force a particular table order; as mentioned, your proposed order sadly results in far worse performance.  I will have a look at temporary table size, although with only 624 records in the resultset I very much doubt this is the problem... indeed, I had understood that `EXPLAIN` showed "using filesort" if temp tables were written to disk?

Comment: one more thought: you have not mentioned if you tried to run the query without the distinct keyword?

Comment: Yes, I have.  As one might expect, without `DISTINCT` there is no need for a temporary table and so results start being returned immediately.  However, as there are ~1.1m non-distinct results, it still takes a while for them to be returned; as mentioned to @N.B. in the comments above, I have little doubt that it is the process of identifying the 624 distinct records from amongst these ~1.1m that is taking the time - I just don't know how to speed that up!  Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know, group by would probably end up doing the same. But I have another idea, what about removing the SpecialKeys join and filtering out the result using an IN subselect in the WHERE clause? The bloody varchar key join is the root of all problems, it's a long key.

Comment: or wrapping the whole select with the SpecialKeys join removed in a new select and filtering it out there on the outside WHERE?

Comment: I updated my answer with the query. I am not sure if I got the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Others might disagree, but I've had and regularly offer STRAIGHT_JOIN for queries... Once you KNOW the data and the relationships.  Being that your WHERE clause is against the "V" table alias and it's "x" value, you are good with the index.  Move THAT to the front position, then join from that.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT
      v.`key`,
      u.`val`
   FROM
      VertexDictionary AS v 

         JOIN ConnectedVertices AS c
            ON v.x = c.head_x
            AND v.y = c.head_y

            JOIN VertexDictionary AS u 
               ON c.tail_x = u.x 
               AND c.tail_y = u.y

               JOIN SpecialKeys AS k
                  ON u.x = k.x
                  AND u.key = k.key
   WHERE
      v.x = {some value}
```

Curious to know how this realignment works for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... sadly your proposed query above takes ~6min (`EXPLAIN` shows ~800k rows being selected from the first/`v` table).

Comment: @eggyal, wow... that really does surprise me... however, how many records is your query returning as ITs result... I'll think more on it hopefully over the weekend.

Comment: The query itself returns 624 records (after `DISTINCT` has been applied; ~1.1m if no `DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the query in stages; or at least give us some more points to identify where the bottlenecks are. Some combinations of the following queries should give you reasonable performance, if it is possible with out modifying the schema or data set.

What is the number of rows and exec times for the following queries for getting the list of suitable tail verticies (ie, that have a SpecialKey)

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    vd.x as tail_x, vd.y as tail_y, vd.val
FROM
    VertexDictionary vd
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            SpecialKeys sk
        WHERE
            vd.x = sk.x
        AND
            vd.key = sk.key
    )
```

or

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    vd.x as tail_x, vd.y as tail_y, vd.val
FROM
    VertexDictionary vd
JOIN
    SpecialKeys sk
ON
    vd.x = sk.x
AND
    vd.key = sk.key
```

or

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    vd.x as tail_x, vd.y as tail_y, vd.val
FROM
    VertexDictionary vd
WHERE
(vd.x, vd.key) IN (SELECT x, key FROM SpecialKeys)
-- also could try vd.key IN (SELECT sk.key FROM SpecialKeys sk WHERE sk.x = vd.x)
```

I'm hoping that one of these returns either small result set, or are at least quick to produce results. if low cardinality & large results apply distinct.

pick the best one from the previous two queries, and add to the next step: joining these suitable 'tails' to 'suitable heads'

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    cv.head_y as y,
    tv.val
FROM
(
    -- ADD SUB QUERY HERE also try nesting the subquery like: (select tail_x, tail_y, val from ([SUBQUERY]) as sq)

) as tv -- tail verticies
JOIN
    ConnectedVerticies cv
ON
    cv.tail_x = tv.tail_x
AND
    cv.tail_y = tv.tail_y
WHERE
    cv.head_x = X -- lets reduce the result set here.
```

Again, I'm hoping that one of these returns either small result set, or are at least quick to produce results. if low cardinality & large results apply distinct.

If it's falling over at this point, well there's not much hope of it getting faster to apply the last phase, and best to try a different approach.

As head x is known from the earlier query, we now just need to join on head_y and X to get v.key

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    inner_query.val,
    head.key
FROM
(
 -- previous nested subquery behemoth here, again, try a few things that might work.

) as inner_query
JOIN
    VertexDictionary as head
ON
    head.x = X
AND
    head.y = inner_query.y
```

Another approach, is to get a list of head.key, tail_x, and tail_y from

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    cv.tail_x as x,
    cv.tail_y as y,
    vd.key
FROM
    VertexDictionary vd
JOIN
    ConnectedVerticies cv
ON
    cv.head_x = vd.x
AND
    cv.head_y = vd.y
WHERE
    vd.head_x = X
```

How long does this take to execute, with & without distinct? how many results (w & w/o distinct)?

If it's fast and/or small, try using it as a subquery and joining to either another subquery potentiall of SpecialKeys & VertexDictionary if that's small (ie one of the first three queries if they worked well).

Comment: I'm aware this isn't a complete "answer" as much as a "build your own". However I'd be happy to at least test these approaches if given a test data set.

Comment: Did you have a go at running any of these queries / or are you able to provide an example data-set?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is everything with the syntax

(`k`.`x`, `k`.`key`) = (`u`.`x`, `u`.`key`)

Can you rewrite as?

k.x = y.x and k.key = u.key

When you have a calculation on the left hand side of a clause, the dbms cannot optimize.  By setting the comparison as a straight comparison, you may improve your performance.

e.g.

year(my_date) = '2012'

is slower than

'2012' = year(my_date)

I'm not sure if mysql treats the comparison as a column comparison or as a calculation.

Please try modifying your query to do column value comparisons.

---

Second optimization

Also - you are cross joining 4 tables.  Multiplication is not additive - is it exponential.  Are you sure this is what you intend?  You may be better served getting starting with the smallest result set and then join only that result set to the next set.

```
select a.c1
from (
select t1.c1
from t1
join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
) a
join t3 on t3.c1 = a.c1
```

etc...

---

third optimization

if option 2 helps, you may want to create indexed views and work from those instead of directly from the tables.

---

fourth optimization

don't use mysql.  unless you have a team of dbas constantly monitoring for performance and tweaks, you will run into bad times with mysql.  mysql is fine and fast with simple things, but starts sucking very badly if you do anything moderately complex.  4 years ago, i migrated from mysql to sql server express and my 10 minute queries took <2 sec with the same tables, indices, and queries...

if you want open source, postgres is much smarter than mysql as well

---

Create a view that incorporates the first 3 tables that is indexed on the v.key, u.val fields.
Then run the query off of the 4th table and the view.  Make sure the indices are built on the view before running.

Comment: Thanks @mson.  I have previously tried your first suggestion to no avail; I think the optimiser already handles this with no difference (grateful if you can point me at references to the contrary, though!).  Your second suggestion is something I have previously tried, also to no avail; I found that creating the arising intermediate tables resulted in worse performance - but perhaps this was due to imperfect optimisation?  Your third suggestion is also something which I have previously tried, and again results in worse performance - see [this blog](http://goo.gl/qe7V3) for details.

Comment: Fourth optimisation is sadly out of the question: this is an incumbent application on an entrenched system.

Comment: you've been thorough...  i'm puzzled by your empirical findings - they don't match the theory.  i don't know if you can provide your schema and data, but this is interesting and i'd love to take a deeper look.

Comment: Is not the schema already provided in the question?  The data is **huge** (and, in any event, confidential) - I could provide some sample data, but it'd be no different to randomly constructing one's own...

Comment: So I elaborated on the view optimization.  It looks like the most expensive bit is the sorting of all the rows.  I'm not saying to create intermediate tables - but to create indexed views with the key specified above.  the creation of the view will be as slow as it is now, but once it's built, subsequent queries on it should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is often a bad friend. Try to replace it with a `GROUP BY`.
Like this :

```
SELECT sub.key, sub.val
FROM (
    SELECT 
      v.key,
      u.val
    FROM
      ConnectedVertices AS c
      JOIN VertexDictionary  AS u ON (u.x, u.y  ) = (c.tail_x, c.tail_y)
      JOIN VertexDictionary  AS v ON (v.x, v.y  ) = (c.head_x, c.head_y)
      JOIN SpecialKeys       AS k ON (k.x, k.key) = (u.x, u.key)
    WHERE (v.x = @X)
) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.key, sub.val
```

**UPDATE:**

Then try the following query which forces the indexes to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v.key,
  u.val
FROM
  ConnectedVertices AS c USE INDEX (fx,rx)
  JOIN VertexDictionary  AS u USE INDEX (primary) ON (u.x, u.y  ) = (c.tail_x, c.tail_y) 
  JOIN VertexDictionary  AS v USE INDEX (primary) ON (v.x, v.y  ) = (c.head_x, c.head_y)
  JOIN SpecialKeys       AS k USE INDEX (primary) ON (k.x, k.key) = (u.x, u.key)
WHERE (v.x = @X)
```

If it still not better, try this one :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v.key,
  u.val
FROM
       ConnectedVertices AS c
  JOIN VertexDictionary  AS u ON (u.x=c.tail_x) AND (u.y=c.tail_y)
  JOIN VertexDictionary  AS v ON (v.x=@X) AND (v.y=c.head_y)
  JOIN SpecialKeys       AS k ON (k.x=u.x) AND (k.key=u.key)
WHERE
  v.x = @X
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Skrol29.  I did try this early on and found performance to be marginally worse, although I don't have the exact amount to hand...

Comment: I will have a go at running the first of your queries tomorrow; the second definitely won't return what I need: the `JOIN` conditions are utterly wrong...

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that forcing uses of specifique indexes is a good think.
the Mysql optimiser has often good estimations.

do you have an index on `v`.`x` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The schema are given in the question; the `VertexDictionary` table has two indices with `x` in the leftmost column: the `PRIMARY KEY` and `dict`.  And I'm not forcing (or even suggesting) use of any specific index, am I?  :s