# Will this query use index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I've got a huge table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `image_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`image_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

on which I have to run a query which compresses the blob field. Will MySQL be able to use index with the following query:

```
UPDATE images SET data = COMPRESS(data) WHERE (user_id = ? AND image_id = ?) OR (user_id = ? AND image_id = ?) OR (...) OR (...);
```

I have to do it like this since there's no way I can update the whole table in a single query and I can't update by only using `user_id`.

EDIT: `explain` and `update` doesn't work, you guys know that, right?

Comment: Take a look at the `explain plan` for the update query and see whether it uses index scan or not.

Comment: Totally unrelated to whether the index will be used or not: do you know you can write the condition as: `WHERE (user_id,image_id) IN ( (?,?), (?,?), ..., (?,?) )`

Comment: @Rahul: It's only possible to see `EXPLAIN` plans for `UPDATE` queries in MySQL >= 5.6

Comment: @ypercube: this one looks nice but won't use the index (at least in `5.5` and below)

Comment: You can see `EXPLAIN` plan for `UPDATE` by replacing UPDATE with SELECT - it will use the same indexes as the select

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your update will use the indexes on the table, since the only columns referred after the `WHERE` are the ones your primary key stands of.

If you are unsure of what a query will use, feel free to use the `EXPLAIN` command:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is only possible for `UPDATE` in MySQL >= 5.6

Comment: True, but still the query can be transformed easily into a SELECT statement, where the selected values are the same. You can assume that the two statements will use a similar plan.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
EXPLAIN SELECT data FROM images
  WHERE (user_id = ? AND image_id = ?)
    OR (user_id = ? AND image_id = ?)
    OR (...)
    OR (...);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I'd expect MySQL to use the primary key as the clustered index.  That means the index stores all columns, and is actually the only version of the data on disk.

So yes, it will use the index.  With a condition including `or`s, I'd expect MySQL to scan the index (not seek.)

Comment: Is scans something to be afraid of? My first attempt used only `image_id = ?` which kind of took down the DB machine.

Comment: Scans can cause a lot of disk I/O.  A good way to avoid them is to run the query for only one image at a time, without `or` in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you Andomar. Update one row per query was my backup plan -- I think I'll do that instead.

Comment: @jim image_id only can't use the index, as the left-most part of the index is not used. So the index can be used on queries that use only user_id, but not on those that use only image_id

Comment: Darhazer yes I know. I ran that query without digging in to the tables indexes. I just assumed that image_id was a sole primary. Stupid, I know.

Answer (score 1):

This is better to check using `EXPLAIN` than to speculate about too much.

Before even running `EXPLAIN`, issue `ANALYZE TABLE` to make sure that the query optimizer has the best chances to find an optimum query plan.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is only possible for `UPDATE` in MySQL >= 5.6

Comment: Good point.  I'm sometimes using a `SELECT` modification as the first approximation when researching variants of a long taking DML statement, but that's just another kind of speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will most probably use the index (unless your conditions have really low cardinality).

`MySQL` also supports this syntax:

```
(user_id, image_id) IN ((user1, image1), (user2, image2), (user3, image3))
```

but this one will not use the index (this is just an implementation flaw).

You can also use this query:

```
UPDATE  (
        SELECT  user1 AS user_id, image1 AS image_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  user2 AS user_id, image2 AS image_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  user3 AS user_id, image3 AS image_id
        ) q
JOIN    images i
ON      (i.user_id, i.image_id) = (q.user_id, q.image_id)
SET     i.data = COMPRESS(i.data)
```

which will also use the index.

Comment: I don't suppose you've already blogged (or can readily locate an article elsewhere) about that implementation flaw?  I'd love to know more (I also wonder whether it is responsible for the problem I faced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211029/optimising-mysql-queries-across-hierarchical-data)).

Comment: @eggyal: uhh, I haven't been blogging for a while so I don't remember, honestly :) Just create a table with composite index and run `EXPLAIN` over this query, you'll see a fullscan even with a `FORCE INDEX`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Does the flaw affect inequality conditions, like this one, too?: `(a,b) <= (1,2)`

Comment: @ypercube: yes, it does. Haven't checked `5.6` yet, but in `5.5` only equalities yield an index seek.